Why "Union" tool doesn't work as "Intersect" tool on the same polygons in QGIS?
I am using QGIS for some basic activities with the land cover vector layer.
I clipped the land cover layer using the mask of a polygon (administrative region) from another layer. Then I used the Union tool and it resulted in 2524 features.
I used also the "Intersect" tool with the same layers and the result was 4276. I noticed that the layer produced by the Union tool has some lines in correspondence with the borders of the polygon (where there is no information), and if I delete them the result coincides with those of the "Intersect" tool.
Why does it happen?
Note:

I modified the original title
Please find attached the geographical difference (these "lines" in correspondence of the borders of the polygon)



Can you add some more details about your input layers and ultimately what you are trying to achieve? From what you have written, the tools are doing what they are supposed to be, but without knowing what you are expecting I am not sure you will get an answer.

The input layers are: clipped Corine Land Cover, according to the geometry of the region and region, divided per municipality. The fact is that I clipped the corine land cover using the polygon that I am using for the union and intersection, but the results are different.

Please add images of each step, that would make it easier to see what you want to do and if there is a problem.

The title references the "Join" tool but the question references the union tool. The text says the Union tool produced 2524 features, the Intersect 4276, but if you delete features from the Union it then matches the Intersect.  How does it match with even fewer features?  I expect visual images will help.

Thank you for your notes. I edited the question and I added an image. The main point is that I used one polygon to clip the Corine Land Cover in the area of my interest, but when I use the same polygon with the Union and the Interect tool, the results are different

It appears you have sliver polygons which typically result from topology issues such as minor overlaps or gaps in the input layers.  You can also get slivers due to additional vertices being introduced in an overlay (typically more than a simple clip) depending on your project snapping tolerances and layer resolution differences.  I usually checked/fixed the geometry and topology of my input layers in any overlay and on the results.  I liked using GRASS v.clean then remove duplicates tool, but snap geometries can work.  If you still have slivers look at the Eliminate tool.
